# Helm Chart and Ingress domain name and SSL

Tags: kubernetes-helm

I will create helm repo for customers. But I'm wondering how you solved the ingress domain name, and ssl parts.

Should I create a custom ingress yaml file for each customer?

Or Should set as follows for each customer?

```
--set "ingress.hosts[0].host=yourhost.com,ingress.hosts[0].paths[0].path=/"
```